# SPARQL: Distinct with different data types

Tags: types, sparql, distinct

I have a request in SPARQL on DBPEDIA, 
I would like to get actors with their birth date, name ...
For instance:

```
select ?actor ?name ?birthDate where { 
    ?actor <http://purl.org/linguistics/gold/hypernym> dbr:Actor ;     
    rdfs:label ?name ; dbo:birthDate ?birthDate .
    filter(?name = "Tom Cruise"@en)
} LIMIT 5
```

I get this result:
[image]

My concern is about the data type of `birthDate`, I am looking for a way to declare a `DISTINCT` type insensitive and so have only one result in the previous request.

Any ideas?

Comment: That is not possible. Even if you just use the lexicalform of the literal with `STR(?birthDate)` you would have to different strings "1962-07-04" and "1962-7-3". That's a problem of the data quality in DBpedia resp. Wikipedia. Data normalization/cleansing is unfortunately up to you in the client code.

Comment: The only way will be to create your own cleaned up data set based on thedbpedia query.

Comment: Do you care *which* of these rows you wind up with?  `SAMPLE` might be the way to go...

Answer (score 2):

First, I think that DBpedia uses only `xsd:date` data type for birthdates, to make sure, you can try out this query:

```
select distinct datatype(?birthDate)  where { 
  ?actor <http://purl.org/linguistics/gold/hypernym> dbr:Actor ;     
  dbo:birthDate ?birthDate .   
}
```

The problem is that some of the values are dirty, as mentioned in the comments, they need to be cleansed. There is some workaround for that, but not sure if it is fine for you.

First, you should guarantee that all formats of the same intended date are unified, so that `DISTINCT` can be used to filter.

For some reason, that I am not really aware of, `xsd:dateTime` shows some tolerance in practice, while it should take values of `yyyy-mm-dd ....`, it accepts values of the form `yyyy-m-d ....`. As a consequence, convert `?birthDate` to `xsd:dateTime`, and then to `xsd:date`. For example, `try select xsd:date (xsd:dateTime ("2000-1-1")) {}`, it results in `"2000-01-01"^^xsd:date`. Somehow, it just works.

Then, and as some data are dirty, you have no option, but to get rid of these data, i.e., values like `2000-0-0` should be excluded. To do this you should make sure that transferring the value of `?birthDate` to the required format succeeds. To this end `( coalesce(xsd:dateTime(xsd:date(?birthDate)), '!') )` would do it, as it returns `'!'` if the `?birthDate` cannot be cast.

I don't have a working query, but this should, in principle, help.

Comment: It does **not** "accept values of the form `yyyy-m-d ....` - it's just wrong and illegal syntax. It's a problem of the data quality in the data and that some triple stores allow for loading those triples without validation syntax of literals.

Comment: @MedianHilal Hi, I am following your answer for one of my projects. I would like to know where DBpedia extracts the information in "http://purl.org/linguistics/gold/hypernym". Please let me know your thoughts :)

Comment: @EmJ Can you please post a question with a detailed explanation of what you need? I cannot clearly get what you are asking.